# Set ACL of multiple group in AD via POWERSHELL

Tags: powershell

sorry but I'm not very good with  Powershell and I need to set the **ACL** permission for 500 security groups in AD, 
in particular I should give the rights of; **WRITE**, **READ** and **DELETE** to  user TEST1 in all groups that i have exported in TXT file, 
I can't understand how to set the access rule .. I tried script below but I don't know if it's ok

```
Set-Location AD:\
$groups = Get-Content c:\groups.txt
foreach ($group In $groups) {
    $ace = (Get-Acl "AD:$((Get-ADgroup $group).DistinguishedName)").Access 
    foreach ($acl in $ace) {
        $accessrule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.ActiceDirectoryAccessRule("domain\test1", "Allow")
        $ace.AddAccessRule($accessrule)
        Set-Acl -AclObject $ace $group.DistinguishedName -Verbose -Passthru
    }
}
```

Comment: "I don't know if it's ok" - looks OK to me :) do you get the expected result if you put one test group in `C:\groups.txt` and look at the security descriptor in a GUI (dsa.msc or ADAC for example)?

Comment: I tried with a test group in txt  but I don't see TEST1 user in acl

Answer (score 0):

Don't loop over the individual existing access control entries, just add your own to the ACL and write it back:

```
Set-Location AD:\
$groups = Get-Content c:\groups.txt
foreach ($group In $groups) {
    $acl = Get-Acl "AD:$((Get-ADgroup $group).DistinguishedName)"
    $accessrule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.ActiceDirectoryAccessRule("domain\test1", "Allow")
    $acl.AddAccessRule($accessrule)
    Set-Acl -AclObject $acl -Path $group.DistinguishedName -Verbose -Passthru
}
```