# powershell add group to group security in AD

Tags: powershell

I can't find a solution.
How can I use PowerShell to add a group to another group in the security tab?
Should I use ACL? If so, has anyone solved this problem and can guide me?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DCedj.jpg)

I try use this solve
[Set ACL of multiple group in AD via POWERSHELL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61800270/set-acl-of-multiple-group-in-ad-via-powershell)

I want to add group 'Kat-VPN1' to group 'Kat-VPN3' but on the security tab

I have code

```
cls
import-module ActiveDirectory$path = "AD:\CN=Kat- 
VPN3,OU=Groups,OU=LOC_1,OU=OFFICE,DC=tm,DC=pl"
$acl = Get-Acl -Path $path
$ace = New-Object Security.AccessControl.ActiveDirectoryAccessRule('DOMAIN\Kat-VPN1','FullControl')
$acl.AddAccessRule($ace)
Set-Acl -Path $path -AclObject $acl
```

Comment: I commend to your attention [Microsoft Learn/Microsoft Ignite on `Add-ADGroupMember`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/add-adgroupmember?view=windowsserver2022-ps).

Comment: I want to add to the security tab. I don't want to add to the members. Refer to the screenshot

Comment: "The Add-ADGroupMember cmdlet adds one or more users, **groups**, service accounts, or computers as new members of an Active Directory group." so you need to read the info on that link given.... (Please!)

Comment: OK. For example"Add-ADGroupMember -Identity Kat-VPN3 -Members Kat-VPN1" The command adds a group to another group members. I want it to be added to the security of the group. Is it possible?

Comment: @TomaszMłynek Yes, you need to modify the ACL of the group. Have a look at [`Set-Acl`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/set-acl?view=powershell-7.3).

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem.

```
# Importing Active Directory module
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

# Defining group names
$groupToAddName = "Kat-VPN1"
$targetGroupName = "Kat-VPN3"

try {
# Getting group objects
$groupToAdd = Get-ADGroup -Filter {Name -eq $groupToAddName}
$targetGroup = Get-ADGroup -Filter {Name -eq $targetGroupName}

# Getting ACL object for the target group
$acl = Get-Acl -Path "AD:\$($targetGroup.DistinguishedName)"

# Getting ACL object for the group to be added
$groupToAddSid = New-Object System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier($groupToAdd.SID.Value)

# Checking if $groupToAddSid is not null
if ($groupToAddSid -ne $null) {
    $groupRule = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectoryAccessRule($groupToAddSid, "WriteProperty, ReadProperty, CreateChild, DeleteChild", "Allow")

    # Adding rule to ACL
    $acl.AddAccessRule($groupRule)

    # Setting updated ACL for the target group
    Set-Acl -Path "AD:\$($targetGroup.DistinguishedName)" -AclObject $acl

    Write-Host "The group $groupToAddName has been added with modify permissions to the ACL of group $targetGroupName."
} else {
    Write-Host "Error creating SecurityIdentifier. Check if the group $groupToAddName exists."
}
} catch {
Write-Host "An error occurred: $_"
```

}

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**